# How to programmatically add a Custom Control to a Form and show it?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

I'm trying to add a Label to a Windows Form by using another class programmatically. My Label does not appear inside the Form.
I don't know where I'm going wrong.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Ticker ticker = new Ticker("ASDF");
     ticker.display();
}

public class Ticker : Label
{
     string labelText;
     Label label = new Label();

     public Ticker(string _labelText)
     {
         labelText = _labelText;
     }
     public void display()
     {
         label.Text = labelText;

         Controls.Add(label);
     }
}
```

Comment: You are adding a label to a label (controls is a property of Ticker : Label).  You want to add the label to the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a few changes to your Ticker Custom Control:

- You don't need to create a new Label *inside* your Custom Control: your Control is already a Label, use the **`this`** reference to set its properties (see also [`this` keyword (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this)).
- The Text is the current Label's Text (`this.Text`). Store it if you need a copy of it for other reasons (custom painting, usually, so sometimes you need to clear the Text).
  **`Controls`** is referring to the current class object: it's a Control, so it has a `Controls` property, which gets the [`ControlCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection) of the child Controls of a Control.
- You need to also specify a Point that defines the position of your Custom Control inside its [Parent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.parent)'s [ClientRectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.clientrectangle).
- Even if it's not always required, add a parameter-less Constructor to your Custom Control: if/when it's actually needed, you'll have it already there.

If you don't want to set the Parent Control from the *outside*, as usual (e.g., `var label = new Label(); this.Controls.Add(label);`), you need to pass the reference of the Control which will become the Parent Control of your custom Label.
You can the use this reference - a `Control` type of reference - and add your Label to the Controls collection of the Control reference you receive:

```
// You want to store a reference to this Control if you need it later...
private Ticker ticker = null;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //... or just declare it with: var ticker = new Ticker() if you don't
    ticker = new Ticker("The Label's Text");
    // [this] of course refers the current class object, Form1
    ticker.Display(this, new Point(100, 100));
    // Or, display the Label inside a Panel, child of Form1
    // Note: if you don't comment the next line, the Label will be moved to panel1
    ticker.Display(this.panel1, new Point(10, 50));
}
```

Here, I'm overloading the `Display()` method, so it accepts both a Parent reference and a `Point` value, used to position the Control inside its Parent's Client Area.
The Custom Label also calls [`BringToFront()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.bringtofront) on itself, to avoid showing up  *under* some other, already existing, child Control of the new `Parent`.

```
public class Ticker : Label
{
    public Ticker() : this("ticker") { }
    public Ticker(string labelText) => this.Text = labelText;

    public void Display(Control parent) => Display(parent, Point.Empty);
    public void Display(Control parent, Point position)
    {
        this.Location = position;
        parent.Controls.Add(this);
        this.BringToFront();
    }
}
```